# How to place these two buttons on the left?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put these two buttons on the left, but to no avail. Can you give me any tips on how to make them stay on the left margin? I've tried to remove the Container and align using only the Row, but without success.

```
Container(
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 70.0, 5.0),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: const Text('CPF'),
                          leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                            value: SingingCharacter.cpf,
                            groupValue: _character,
                            onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _character = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: const Text('RNE'),
                          leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                            value: SingingCharacter.rne,
                            groupValue: _character,
                            onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _character = value;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Comment: can you please provide some image and full body code?

Comment: What kind of layout do you want exactly ? 2 buttons in one half of the row and empty in the second half ?

Comment: I put the complete code and an image to facilitate what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

ListTile occupies an entire row, and if you wrap each ListTile with Expanded widget then it gets divided into 2 ListTile in the same row.
So if you want to create 2 Radio's and align them into the left row, then don't use listTile and expanded.

Instead create a row, pass 2 columns. Each column will have 2 Widgets. A text widget and a Radio Widget. That's how you can achieve your desired outlook.

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(),
  body: Column(children: [
    Row(
      children: [
        Column(
          children: [
            const Text("Radio 1"),
            Radio<SingingCharacter>(
              value: SingingCharacter.cpf,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 20,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            const Text("Radio 2"),
            Radio<SingingCharacter>(
              value: SingingCharacter.rne,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
  ]),
);
```

Comment: Buttons went further to the left, but became more misaligned.
I've put the full code below if it helps.

Comment: I put the complete code and an image to facilitate what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

```
Container(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 5.0, 70.0, 5.0),
              child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, // add this line
                children: [
                 // Expanded(
                  //  child: 
                ListTile(
                      title: const Text('CPF'),
                      leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                        value: SingingCharacter.cpf,
                        groupValue: _character,
                        onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _character = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),

                  // ),
                  // Expanded(
                  //  child: 

                   ListTile(
                      title: const Text('RNE'),
                      leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                        value: SingingCharacter.rne,
                        groupValue: _character,
                        onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _character = value;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    ),

                  // ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: It didn't work, I put all the code below

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I put the complete code and an image to facilitate what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

the closest I got was using this code:

```
Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child:
                      ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0,),
                        title: const Text('CPF'),
                        leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                          value: SingingCharacter.cpf,
                          groupValue: _character,
                          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _character = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child:
                      ListTile(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0,),
                        title: const Text('RNE'),
                        leading: Radio<SingingCharacter>(
                          value: SingingCharacter.rne,
                          groupValue: _character,
                          onChanged: (SingingCharacter? value) {
                            setState(() {
                              _character = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```